# How to specify best spline for this data

Tags: python, scipy, spline

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47]
y = [31031.4,35241.7,42320.8,38146.7,38345.9,42320.8,33649.2,42883.3,35459,36371.6,23259.8,53740.6,36971.6,29518.3,45773,51421.43,56303.5,38786,31956.4,42717,43026.88,58479.4,50628.24,33375.19,40332.36,52731.29,48409.99,62328.65,48409.99,53941.38,52736.68,55794.38,48180.88,42949.35,48234.66,49505.83,50629.87,25361.3,57403.21,46805.93,55834.61,24978.13,51037.43,46727.27,31766.46,21553.01,34017.05,31533.17]
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=5)
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y)
print(spl.get_knots())
xs = np.linspace(0, 47, 1000)
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'g', lw=3)
#spl.set_smoothing_factor(1000000000)
#plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'b', lw=3)
plt.show()
```

I have the graphic where spline goes through the all points (screen 1), but I need the graphic like on screen 2.
Screen 1:
[image]

Screen 2:
[image]

Comment: Firstly, there are two curves in the second image. Secondly, it seems these two curves have been generated as splines of sets of knots derived from the given set of points, but there is no information about how these new sets of knots are computed. Also, how do you got the second image in the first place?

Comment: https://github.com/Quanteeks/Splines, got the second image from here, it was done without scipy

Answer (score 1):

UnivariateSpline has a smoothing parameter `s`, see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html).

> Positive smoothing factor used to choose the number of knots. Number of knots will be increased until the smoothing condition is satisfied:
>
> `sum((w[i] * (y[i]-spl(x[i])))**2, axis=0) <= s`

Since your y values are quite big your smoothing factor also has to be big (or you could normalize your data, see below).

```
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=1e9)
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Normalization:

```
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y/np.max(y))
xs = np.linspace(0, 47, 1000)
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs)*np.max(y), 'g', lw=3)
```

Here `s = len(w)` (see link, `w` are the weights), which is the default.
Plot:

[image]

```
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y/np.max(y), s=float(len(y))*0.017)
xs = np.linspace(0, 47, 1000)
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs)*np.max(y), 'g', lw=3)
```

looks similar to your plot:

[image]

Comment: really nice! but how did you manage to get this 0.017 coefficient?)

Comment: Trial and error. Unless you have a formal definition of what your expected curve should look like there isnt much else you can do..

Comment: If i knew, man) This is my diploma of bachelor degree. My scientific director doesn't know exactly what spline I need too. Russian education, you know. She just says that I need the best:D in my opinion.

Comment: Yes,this is trade balance

Comment: If there is a model for this you might want to look into the kalman filter